# How to prove an implication about an upper bound mentioned in the proof of master theorem?

Tags: algorithms

[image]

How can we prove rigorously the proposition "Suppose the if in case 1 is true, the equation 4.23 is true"? 
For given constant b and j, the implication in green makes sense. If the upper bound of j was fixed, the equation 4.23 follows directly. However, when n increases, the upper bound of j also increases, though is slower. It is where I find difficult to prove there always exists a value m > 0 such that for all n >= m, equation 4.23 is true.

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics (note that you can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands)) and don't forget to give proper attribution to your sources!

Comment: Related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/135707/justifying-a-claim-in-the-proof-of-the-master-theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement $f = O(h)$ just states that there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $f(N) \leq Ch(N)$ for all $N$ (some variants have this hold only for large enough $N$, but in most cases there is no difference). In your case, $f(N) \leq CN^{\log_b a-\epsilon}$ for all $N$. This holds for $N = n/b^j$ in particular, and implies that
$$
g(n) \leq C \sum_{j=0}^{\log_b n-1} a^j (n/b_j)^{\log_b a-\epsilon}.
$$

As for the two different definitions of big O: suppose that $f(N) \leq CN^{\log_b a-\epsilon}$ holds only for $N \geq N_0$, and let $M = \max(C,f(1),\ldots,f(N_0))$. Then $f(N) \leq MN^{\log_b a-\epsilon}$.

Comment: I am using the book, https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-3rd-MIT-Press/dp/0262033844, which defines the big-o notation as the variant you mentioned, and so I cannot assume the existence of constant C for all N as you suggest. My concern is when j grows as n grows, what is value N0 such that the inequality holds for all N >= N0.

Comment: In the last paragraph I explain why $N_0$ isn’t necessary in this case.